# Как получить рендж функцией, а не синтаксисом листа?

Tags: haskell

```hs
\n -> [0..n]
```

Можно ли записать эту лямбду в point free нотации без написания отдельной функции? Т.е. чтобы можно было сделать цепочку вызовов типа `[0..?] $ n`.

Comment: Пожалуйста, поясните Вашу проблему. Из Вашего вопроса мне не понятно, зачем именно нужно писать такую цепочку, если можно написать просто ```[0..n]```

Answer (score 1):

```hs
[x .. y]
```

это синтаксический сахар для

```hs
enumFromTo x y
```

то же самое и с другими вариантами этой конструкции

```hs
[x ..]       -- enumFrom x
[x, y ..]    -- enumFromThen x y
[x, y .. z]  -- enumFromThenTo x y z
```

Т.е. в бесточечном виде ваша функция будет выглядеть так

```
enumFromTo 0
```